# XSLT to HTML, storing information about two parties and then do a lookup for each parties activities

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file that I am trying to convert into a dynamic HTML page by using XSLT.

XML is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chatTranscript startAt="2016-11-03T08:29:13Z" sessionId="0001KaC1NSN60019">
    <newParty userId="0079581AF5590023" timeShift="0" visibility="ALL" eventId="1">
        <userInfo personId="" userNick="10.50.24.202" userType="CLIENT" protocolType="FLEX" timeZoneOffset="120"/>
        <userData>
            <item key="GMSServiceId">c0aa6221-d5f9-4fdc-9f75-ed63e99b1f12</item>
            <item key="IdentifyCreateContact">3</item><item key="MediaType">chat</item>
            <item key="TimeZone">120</item><item key="_data_id">139-9a8ee95b-d3ba-43a2-93a9-08ed7965d63d</item>
            <item key="firstName">Mike</item>
            <item key="lastName">Kumm</item>
        </userData>
    </newParty>
    
    <newParty userId="0079581AF56C0025" timeShift="20" visibility="ALL" eventId="2">
        <userInfo personId="1" userNick="allendei" userType="AGENT" protocolType="BASIC" timeZoneOffset="120"/>
    </newParty>
    
    <message userId="0079581AF56C0025" timeShift="32" visibility="ALL" eventId="4">
    <msgText treatAs="NORMAL">Hello</msgText></message>
    <message userId="0079581AF5590023" timeShift="62" visibility="ALL" eventId="5">
    <msgText msgType="text" treatAs="NORMAL">Can you help me?</msgText></message>
    <notice userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="246" visibility="ALL" eventId="3">
      <noticeText noticeType="USER_CUSTOM">This is notice one.</noticeText>
    </notice>

    <notice userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="246" visibility="ALL" eventId="3">
     <noticeText noticeType="USER_CUSTOM">This is notice two.</noticeText>
    </notice>



    <partyLeft userId="007957F616780001" timeShift="291" visibility="ALL" eventId="4" askerId="007957F616780001">
     <reason code="3">left due to disconnect</reason>
    </partyLeft>
</chatTranscript>
```

A rough outline of what I would like my HTML to look like is as follows:

```html
<html>
    <header>Session ID: 0001KaC1NSN60019</header>
    <div class="Client" id="0079581AF5590023">
        <label>Client: 10.50.24.202</label>
    </div>
    <div class="Agent" id="0079581AF56C0025">
        <label>Agent: allendei</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="Messages" id="4">
        <label>Hello</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="Messages" id="5">
        <label>Can you help me?</label>
    </div>
</html>
```

This is crock-pot of what I would like to have, the necessary references and relationships (agent vs client, their details being remembered, and when the messages are printed out, to actually put each message in a div with the correct class name to ensure that I can apply a different style to each method.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post the **exact** code you expect to get as the result of transforming the given example.

Comment: I edited the question to contain the exact xml I would like. Important to note taht the two divs at the bottom are tied to the Client and Agent, in the fact that it is their messages. I

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "tied". I don't see anything that ties them.

Comment: its what i am asking, how to tie / do a lookup.

Comment: What I am asking is what exactly do you want to lookup, from where to where? Currently, you show no value in the message `div`s that needs to come from the authoring party, or vice versa.

Comment: I added some quotes `"` to your desired HTML output to make it well-formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output really is the desired one, use this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/chatTranscript">
      <html>
        <header><xsl:value-of select="@sessionId" /></header>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="newParty" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="message/msgText" />
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='CLIENT']">
      <div class="Client" id="{@userId}">
        <label>Client: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" /></label>
      </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="newParty[userInfo/@userType='AGENT']">
      <div class="Client" id="{@userId}">
        <label>Agent: <xsl:value-of select="userInfo/@userNick" /></label>
      </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="msgText">
      <div class="Messages" id="{../@eventId}">
        <label><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></label>
      </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
    <header>0001KaC1NSN60019</header>
    <div class="Client" id="0079581AF5590023">
        <label>Client: 10.50.24.202</label>
    </div>
    <div class="Client" id="0079581AF56C0025">
        <label>Agent: allendei</label>
    </div>
    <div class="Messages" id="4">
        <label>Hello</label>
    </div>
    <div class="Messages" id="5">
        <label>Can you help me?</label>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to do - thank you. I know this is a separate question - but how would I build in logic so that for the message sent by the Agent I can put another class, called Agent (and likewise for Client)? I would post another question but is afraid that the already built up context would be lost.

Comment: I also have another tag similar to the Messages tag - called Notice. When I replicate the Notice tag in xsl, it does not print anything out. (I shared the minimum initially as I did not want to complicate things, and thought once I get an answer I will be able to derive other rules. I'm updating the original code to reflect what I mean.

Comment: I found the solution to the Notice field not showing up. Looking at tying the messages to either an agent or a client as a next step.